# Can I do remote debug of two different projects at the same time using intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have two java (maven) projects, A (with module a1, a2, a3) and B (with module b1,b2,b3,b4).
Both these two projects are packaged as jar file and deployed in jboss server.
There are some API invocation between these two projects (using REST and EJB invocation). 
I am able to remote debugging these projects individually (say I am debugging project A first then after A is completely over, I can start debugging the other) using intellij.

Now, my question is – 
Can I do remote debugging of two different java projects at the same time using intellij?

Please note that I have imported the projects into intellij as maven projects.

Comment: If they run on different ports, probably...

Comment: MadProgrammer .. I have configured the jboss as

-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n

How can I configure two ports

Comment: The Java process need to a different `address=` pointing to a different port, then you need to create a new "Remote Debugger" for each port in Intellij, pointing to these port numbers...

Comment: thanks for your update. Can I configure jboss as

 -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y  suspend=y -jar a.jar

 -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8002,server=y  suspend=y -jar b.jar


I have tried it but I am still facing the same problem

Comment: Are the two packages running in the same JBoss instance? If so, you can only configure one debug port, but you'll be able to debug both applications using the same remote debug configuration.

Comment: @Nebelmann yes both packages are running in the same JBoss instance. Can you suggest me how to debug both application at the same time using single port??

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I have tried the same thing in Intellij 14 and was able to just open the parent directory (both projects in the same directory) and start my remote debugger there. It then lets me debug both projects.

Answer (score 0):

Considering what's been said in the comments, it seems that you are deploying two applications in the same JBoss instance (so there's only one debug port).

Two possibilities:

- your applications are in separate IntelliJ projects => you can [import existing modules from project A to project B](https://janikvonrotz.ch/2019/01/11/open-multiple-projects-in-intellij/) in order to have all the modules in the same IntelliJ project, then a single debug config should work for all modules. Importing existing modules will simulate what's called a "workspace" in Eclipse.
- your applications are already in the same IntelliJ project (two modules) => create a single debug configuration

In both cases, you should be able to set breakpoints and debug as usual in both applications.

Comment: Sorry Bastien, just a curiosity...You mean that if I have a JBoss instance running remotely, and if I configure Eclipse on two different laptop with the same Java Remote App configuration (socket attach way with same host and port), it means that is possible to debug concurrently on the same (for example same Java classes) JBoss server instance?

Comment: No, remote debuggers only accept one connection at a time.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Hence, I suppose there could not exist any workaround to do it right?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot connect two separate IntelliJ projects to the same debug port on the same JBoss instance - the first possibility is simply not working! That is the biggest drawback when working with IntelliJ compared to using Eclipse.

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer to suggest another approach: import modules from different projects in the same IntelliJ project to mimic Eclipse workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I wanted to debug the actual code of `two jars` my project is using, and `the source code of these jars exists on my machine`

so to do that:

1. from project tab on the left search for your library that you have its source code
   [image]
2. right click on it and chose `open library settings`

you might see something like this (red line indicator of missing sources files)

[image]

click on green add (+) button and add navigate to the project directory of the jar library

[image]

now you will have it like this

[image]

click apply and ok.

now the debugger will hit the source code of the library as it is a part of the project